# Bootstrap modal is working on inserting and updating on database, problem is that bootstrap alert is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

here is the front end for this project, I am searching for days for the solution for this but still no luck, I am a beginner to bootstrap and PHP.

```html
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Shout Box!</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- Form -->
          <form class="text-center" style="color: #757575;" id="shoutOutForm" name="shoutOutForm"
            action="shouts.php" method="POST">
            <!-- Form Start -->
            <section class="forms">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Page Header-->
                <div id="buttonAlert"></div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <?php
                        $user_id = $wo["user"]["id"];
                      ?>

                        <input type="text" id="sigaw" name="sigaw" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" id="username" name="username" value="<?= $user_id ?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
        </div><!-- End Modal Body -->
        <!-- Form End -->
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-success" id="shoutOutBtn" data-loading-text="Shouting..."> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Shout</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Close</button>
        </div>
          <!-- possible cause of undesired error, not OP comment! -->
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the script for this project, this is where I am stuck, been searching google for days. The response is not working.

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // submit customers form function
    $("#shoutOutForm").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
      $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
      $('.text-danger').remove();
      var sigaw = $("#sigaw").val();
      var username = $("#username").val();
      if(sigaw == "") {
        $("#sigaw").after('<p class="text-danger">Shout Out field is required</p>');
        $('#sigaw').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
      } else {
        // remov error text field
        $("#sigaw").find('.text-danger').remove();
        // success out for form
        $("#sigaw").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
      }
      if(sigaw) {
          var form = $(this);
          // button loading
          $("#shoutOutBtn").button('loading');
          $.ajax({
            url : form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
              $('#shoutOutBtn').html("<div class='spinner-border text-light' role='status'></div> Shouting ...");
              $("#shoutOutBtn").prop('disabled', true); // disable button
            },
              success:function(response) {
                // button loading
                $("#shoutOutBtn").button('reset');
                  if(response.success == true) {
                    // reload the manage member table
                    // reset the form text
                    $("#shoutOutForm")[0].reset();
                    // remove the error text
                    $(".text-danger").remove();
                    // remove the form error
                    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
                    $('#buttonAlert').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+
                      '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+
                      '<strong><i class="fa fa-check"></i></strong> '+ response.messages +
                      '</div>');
                    $(".alert-success").delay(500).show(10, function() {
                      $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                        $("#shoutOutBtn").prop('disabled', false); // disable button
                        $('#shoutOutBtn').html("<i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i> Save");
                      });
                    }); // /.alert
                  } else {
                    $("#shoutOutForm")[0].reset();
                    // remove the error text
                    $(".text-danger").remove();
                    // remove the form error
                    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

                    $('#buttonAlert').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                      '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+
                      '<strong><i class="fa fa-check"></i></strong> '+ response.messages +
                      '</div>');
                    $(".alert-danger").delay(500).show(10, function() {
                      $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                        $("#shoutOutBtn").prop('disabled', false); // disable button
                        $('#shoutOutBtn').html("<i class=\"fa fa-cross\"></i> Save");
                      });
                    }); // /.alert
                  }
              } // /success
          }); // /ajax
      } // if
      return false;
    });  // submit customers form function
  });
</script>
```

> a filler text, I remove unnecessary original OP sentence, he says it twice.

Comment: post `shouts.php` content here

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You said php then java, did you meant javascript? it's not the same language and you don't need them to fix a layout behavior

Comment: Your second snippet, it contains syntax errors, I am sure even you are able to handle that. Keep in mind to write an answerable q.